# How to make a steel mold from a 3D print in high detailed resin?

Tags: print-quality, 3d-models, 3d-design, resolution

I'm looking for information on how to make a steel mold from 3D print model using high detailed Resin.

My model is a custom made figurine/mininature of 6 inch.

Can anyone share companies that can make high detailed steel molds either in US or China.

Thanks,
-Uday.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I voted to close your question as primarily opinion-based. We focus on technical questions here, that have more-or-less objective answers. As such, asking for (a list of) companies that do X doesn't fit very well with StackExchange's framework. Please see http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. You could improve your question by focussing more on (a specific) technical aspect about mould making, but asking for a general overview of the process might be too broad.

Comment: Hi, Bhaskar, and welcome to 3D Printing SE! As described by Tom, questions asking for "the best" provider, filament, printer etc. are usually discouraged for being *primarily opinion based*. I therefore have to put your question *on hold* for now. A better suited question would be to ask about the details of molding techniques, and similar (as long as they relate to 3D Printing!). :-)

Comment: Sorry about that! Please delete the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have proven demand, you should start with aluminum tooling. It's *much* cheaper than steel, and (I'm assuming you want this for injection molding) you can produce quite a decent amount of parts from aluminum tooling if you handle it carefully.

Why do you want your tooling to be based on a 3D print model? Typically, for greatest accuracy, the tool and die company works from your original CAD work that you printed the 3D model from.

In terms of companies, Protolabs does plastic injection molding: https://www.protolabs.com/injection-molding/plastic-injection-molding/

Comment: Thanks a lot for inputs, this 3D model is made of ZBrush (STL file). Can this file help in making CAD work? Here is the sculpture in the original. https://globindian.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/bajirao-peshwa-hindu-king-ranveer-singh-india-love-story-3.jpg

Comment: @Bhaskar What formats are accepted will depend somewhat on the tool and die company. Protolabs claims to accept STL files. https://www.protolabs.com/resources/faqs From a technical standpoint, STL is reasonably well suited to tool and die applications, and can be expected to work great for art. SolidWorks is probably slightly better for technical parts.